# Is there a MIME Type for FreeMarker templates?

Tags: mime-types, freemarker, content-type

I need to distinguish between different type of HTML templates, e.g. a FreeMarker from an Handlebars template. Since the templates are in a database (so they are not files, i.e. no filename nor extension) I'd like to use MIME types to identify them.

For Handlebars there is a custom MIME type largely used: `text/x-handlebars-template`, but I can't find one for FreeMarker.

I understand I can use a custom one, e.g. `text/ftl+html`, but I'd like to use the right one if it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any. (The `text/ftl+html` you mention is I guess for `.ftlh` files, but shouldn't it have an `x-` in it as well?)

Answer (score 0):

Though my answer is over a year late, would it not be better to default to `text/html` type? As I found in the [freemarker version changes](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/versions_2_1_2.html) list dating back to 2002, the freemarker servlet will respond by default to the **ContentType** (`text/html`).